# Fit colliding elements in the container dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-collision

I have absolutely positioned elements with different `position.top` and `height` generated from database.

All I'm trying to do is to un-collide these elements by shifting them to the right while adjusting width to fit inside the `<body>` container.

I'm having an issue applying 'left' position to the collided elements.

I use https://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/ to detect collision.

Here is how the final picture should look:

[image: screenshot]

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).text();
  var hits = $(this).collision('div').not(this); // Find colliding elements
  console.log(name + ' collides with: ' + hits.length + ' others');

  if (hits.length > 0) {
    var widthAll = 100 / (hits.length + 1);

    // Shift colliding elements to the right with equal width
    $(hits).add(this).each(function(i) {
      var name = $(this).text();
      $(this).css({ 'left': widthAll * i + '%', 'width': widthAll + '%' });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: white;
}

.blue {
  top: 0;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  top: 15%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  top: 17%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.green {
  top: 30%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: green;
}

.magenta {
  top: 36%;
  height: 3%;
  background-color: magenta;
}

.cyan {
  top: 50%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: black;
}

.brown {
  top: 81%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dsbaars/jquery-collision/master/js/jquery-collision.min.js"></script>

<div class='blue'>blue</div>
<div class='red'>red</div>
<div class='yellow'>yellow</div>
<div class='green'>green</div>
<div class='magenta'>magenta</div>
<div class='cyan'>cyan</div>
<div class='brown'>brown</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have completed your code as you have requested. The idea is,

1. First block of code shifts the divs to the right so that they don't overlap.
2. Second block makes the width of the divs evenly distributed according to size of the body.
3. Last block increases the width of rest of the divs to take remaining space.

```js
"use strict";
var divs = $('div'),
  mx = 0,
  mxs = [0],
  bw = $("body").outerWidth(),
  steps = 1;
divs.each(function(i) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < divs.length; j++) {
    if (!$(this).data("x")) $(this).data("x", 0);
    if (j < divs.length) {
      var hit = $(this).collision(divs[j]);
      if (hit.length) {
        hit = $(divs[j]);
        hit.css("left", "+=" + Math.ceil($(this).outerWidth()));
        hit.data("x", hit.position().left);
        if (mx < hit.data("x")) {
          mxs.push(mx = hit.data("x"));
          steps++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

divs.each(function(i) {
  let iw = $(this).outerWidth(),
    fw = bw / steps;
  $(this).outerWidth(fw);
  for (var j = i + 1; j < divs.length; j++) {
    $(this).collision(divs[j]).css("left", "+=" + Math.ceil((fw - iw) * mxs.indexOf($(divs[j]).data("x"))));
  }
});
divs.each(function() {
  var os = $(this).outerWidth(),
    ts = bw - $(this).position().left;
  $(this).outerWidth(ts);
  if ($(this).collision(divs).not(this).length) {
    $(this).outerWidth(os);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
}
.blue {
  top: 0;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  top: 15%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: red;
}
.yellow {
  top: 17%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
.green {
  top: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
.magenta {
  top: 36%;
  height: 3%;
  background-color: magenta;
}
.cyan {
  top: 50%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: black;
}
.brown {
  top: 81%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dsbaars/jquery-collision/master/js/jquery-collision.min.js"></script>

<div class='blue'>blue</div>
<div class='red'>red</div>
<div class='yellow'>yellow</div>
<div class='green'>green</div>
<div class='magenta'>magenta</div>
<div class='cyan'>cyan</div>
<div class='brown'>brown</div>
```

Above snippet is non-responsive. If you wish it to be responsive, then simply listen to resize event, change the value of `bw` and repeat code blocks 2 and 3.

**As mentioned in the comments:** jquery-collision.min.js had some unressolved bugs so, as suggested by **Alex G**, https://www.48design.de/de/news/2009/11/20/kollisionsabfrage-per-jquery-plugin-update-v11/ may be an alternative.

Comment: It still overlaps if I change `top` and `height` of some elements. https://jsfiddle.net/n5hLehga/ screenshot: https://s28.postimg.org/a14zkpsv1/Untitled.png

Comment: @AlexG I am quite surprised to see same code working fine in this site when we press "Run code snippet", while breaks down when in jsfiddle. Anyway I will have a look further to debug this unusual behaviour.

Comment: @AlexG I can see some instances where jquery-collision plugin failed to work as expected. Maybe, we could use other alternatives or even build our own plugin for intersection detection.

Comment: jsfiddle surprises me once in a while... thank you for your hard work... the code works great... a little suggestion: replace `width` with `outerWidth` (so you can play with `div` paddings without issues).

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion. I have edited the answer with changes that you suggested.

Comment: One other thing: somehow your formula strictly depends on 10em of div width. If 10em has any different value - everything breaks. =)

Comment: Well I don't think so. It will work with anything less, as it took care of growth in width, not shrinking. There is "+=" in width, which will relatively increase width, but breaks when needs to decrease

Comment: I was having troubles: compare these two http://jsfiddle.net/4sL3fvvf/2/embedded/result and http://jsfiddle.net/4sL3fvvf/1/embedded/result. First one works okay, the second one doesn't stretch divs. The only difference is css height values! It was `jquery-collision` plugin issue. I replaced it with https://www.48design.de/de/news/2009/11/20/kollisionsabfrage-per-jquery-plugin-update-v11/ and everything works now. You may want to update your answer.

Comment: There is a bug in your code: https://jsfiddle.net/56ww0mac/1/embedded/result cyan block is overlapping with yellow. Could you please look into that? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is a bug. I will try to figure out workaround moments later.

Comment: I was away on a trip so, I couldn't focus on a workaround. Here is a quick fix for the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/56ww0mac/2/